# PowerShell sometimes fail to execute .exe

Tags: powershell, webdeploy, invoke-command

I am trying to script something to sync up IIS servers using MSdeploy.

I tried all the possible ways to run the .exe but sometimes I get this error:

```
The term 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' is 
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

When I execute the same script again after running it the first time it works fine. This is how I ended up calling it:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' -verb:sync ...
```

Any ideas how to prevent it from failing the first time?

Comment: Is it possible something in your script is modifying the PATH env var so that upon a second execution, PowerShell is able to find msdeploy.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use the powershell cmdlets provided by Web Deploy instead of using the exe? These cmdlets get installed by default since V3.

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend that people use the `Start-Process` cmdlet to call external executables.

```
$MsDeploy = 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe';
$ArgumentList = '-verb:sync ... ... ...';
Start-Process -FilePath $MsDeploy -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow;
```

Comment: I have tried it the same way you suggested but I still get the same error on the first run.

Comment: If the exe is a console app, which msdeploy.exe is, I don't see much benefit to using Start-Process except to maybe use -verb runas to launch an elevated console to run the app.  And passing parameters is a bit more of pain using -ArgumentList.

Comment: I find that `-ArgumentList` makes things a lot easier. You don't have to worry about quoting rules quite as much, and it's easier to build your arguments separate from invoking the console executable.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `C:\Program Files` gets redirected for 32-bit processes, so

1. Make sure you're starting the same process bitness for powershell.exe (or whatever is hosting PowerShell).
2. Use $env:ProgramFiles for a more robust script and put it in quotes along with the full path since the path will likely have spaces in it.

To always use the 32-bit powershell process, on a 32-bit machine run:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1\powershell.exe
```

On a 64-bit machine, run:

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1\powershell.exe
```